# WPF - Value inside datagrid fails to update converter when changed externally

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

Turns out it's surprisingly hard to bubble up property changes from items inside an ObservableCollection - by default it only raises changed events when the collection itself is modified, not the items within it.

This SO answer (to another of my questions on the subject) suggested that one way round the problem was to use a converter:

[WPF MVVM - Datagrid does not update changed properties of child items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22842894/wpf-mvvm-datagrid-does-not-update-changed-properties-of-child-items)

And for one of my scenarios, where the style of an item is dependent on its value and that value can be changed via the user editing the DataGrid, it works beautifully.

However, in the same DataGrid it's possible to update another field by pressing a button - the button is in the same ViewModel, but it doesn't belong to the datagrid itself. I tried a similar trick to get this to work:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Status" Binding="{Binding Status}" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource BookingBackgroundConverter}" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

And the converter:

```
public class BookingBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Booking b = (Booking)value;

        switch(b.Status)
        {
            case "Booking" :
                return Brushes.LightBlue;
            case "Booked" :
                return Brushes.LightGreen;
            default :
                return Brushes.Transparent;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Incidentally I was surprised that the value going into the Converter turned out to be a Booking - that's what the *row* is bound to, not the *column - I was expecting to get the string value of Status. Might be useful to know why that is, as it may have a bearing on the answer.

Anyway, here's the button click command that changes the Status:

```
private void BookCount()
{
    SelectedBooking.Status = "Booking";
    rep.SaveChanges();
    OnPropertyChanged("");
}
```

SelectedBooking is a property that holds the currently selected row. And I'm firing an empty OnPropertyChanged in desperation to try and get this to update.

But no joy - the converter code doesn't get hit until the View reloads. Why does the converter approach work for datagrid edits but not button clicks, and what can I do to get the button click to visually update the status column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change `Status` but you bind whole `Booking` object which means it will trigger only when whole object changes and not when any property from within that object changes. Bind `Status` instead

```
<Binding Path=Status, Converter="{StaticResource BookingBackgroundConverter}" />
```

and change converter to work with your booking status instead of `Booking` object. If you need to pass multiple values use [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) with [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx)

Comment: This doesn't actually work, but +1 for teaching me that you need to specify a Path in a single value converter - I thought it inferred this automatically.

Comment: What does not work? Converter still is not called when `Status` value changes? Does `Booking` class implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`?

Comment: No, the Booking doesn't implement INotifyPropertyChanged. It's an Entity Framework class. Elsewhere this hasn't been a problem because I've been adding INotfiyPropertyChanged to the ViewModel and exposing objects through that. I'm not clear why Booking does update when the grid is edited though, but not on button click

Comment: Edit implies value change so it will refresh you data and button click doesn't. If it's EF object then best solution would be to create view model wrapper as you did elsewhere.